# Objective C Function Question

Tags: objective-c

Hey guys, check this out. I have a function that treats for me a string. No matter what it does, i just want to knwo if is possible to this function return the result for the place that it was executed. I mean, check this:

```
[self priceFormat:@"1"];
priceLabel.text = price;


-(void) priceFormat:(NSString*)price {

price = @"2";

}
```

I just want to my function treats the string and return it to the same place that it was executed.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a method, not a function.

Comment: Could you clarify what your intent is?  Your logic doesn't make sense, a little more context would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Three ways to do this

### Way one, using a pointer

```
- (void)priceFormat:(NSString **)price {
  *price = @"2";
}
```

---

### Wat two, using an instance variable

What you might want instead is an ivar. In the interface (most often the `h` file) of your class:

```
NSString *price;
```

and in the implementation (the `m` or `mm` file):

```
- (void)priceFormat:(NSString *)price {
  price = @"2";
}
```

I have created an example of this [here](http://voidptr.heroku.com/pastes/9dfe02b3dd3c4676d438eab5141b15166895ba63).

---

If you want the price to be available to other objects as well (not just `self`), you might want to create a property for it and synthesize it. Then use `self.price = @"2";` instead. More on this here: http://MacDeveloperTips.com/objective-c/objective-c-properties-setters-and-dot-syntax.html

**Just make sure you make it a `copy` property (NSString in use)!**

---

### Way three using `return`

Note, that you can also return directly from a method:

```
- (NSString *)priceFormat:(NSString *)price {
  return @"2";
}

priceLabel.text = [self priceFormat:@"1"];
```

Comment: Perfect man. Sometimes i forget some essentials things. Thanks a lot.